# Convergence of $\sqrt{n}x_{n}$ where $x_{n+1} = \sin(x_{n})$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence defined as

$x_1 = 1$

$x_{n+1} = \sin x_n$

I think I was able to show that the sequence $\sqrt{n} x_{n}$ converges to $\sqrt{3}$ by a tedious elementary method which I wasn't too happy about.

(I think I did this by showing that $\sqrt{\frac{3}{n+1}} < x_{n} < \sqrt{\frac{3}{n}}$, don't remember exactly)

This looks like it should be a standard problem.

Does anyone know a simple (and preferably elementary) proof for the fact that the sequence $\sqrt{n}x_{n}$ converges to $\sqrt{3}$?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Before getting into the details, let me say: The ideas I'm talking about, including this exact example, can be found in chapter 8 of *Asymptotic Methods in Analysis* (second edition), by N. G. de Bruijn. This is a really superb book, and I recommend it to anyone who wants to learn how to approximate quantities in "calculus-like" settings. (If you want to do approximation in combinatorial settings, I recommend Chapter 9 of *Concrete Mathematics*.)

Also, this isn't just about $\sin$. Let $f$ be a function with $f(0)=0$ and $0 \leq f(u) < u$ for $u$ in $(0,c]$ then the sequence $x_n:=f(f(f(\cdots f(c)\cdots)$ approaches $0$. If $f(u)=u-a u^{k+1} + O(u^{k+2})$ (with $a>0$) then $x_n \approx \alpha n^{-1/k}$ and you can prove that by the same methods here.

Having said that, the answer to your question. On $[0,1]$, we have
$$\sin x=x-x^3/6+O(x^5).$$
Setting $y_n=1/x_n^2$, we have
$$1/x_{n+1}^2 = x_n^{-2} \left(1-x_n^2/6+O(x_n^4) \right)^{-2} =  1/x_n^2 + 1/3 + O(x_n^2)$$
so
$$y_{n+1} = y_n + 1/3 + O(y_n^{-1}).$$

We see that
$$y_n = \frac{n}{3} + O\left( \sum_{k=1}^n y_k^{-1} \right)$$
and
$$\frac{1}{n}y_n = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{n} O\left( \sum_{k=1}^n y_k^{-1} \right)$$
Since we already know that $x_n \to 0$, we know that $y_n^{-1} \to 0$, so the average goes to zero and we get $\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n/n=1/3$. Transforming back to $\sqrt{n} x_n$ now follows by the continuity of $1/\sqrt{t}$.

Comment: PS This is a good example of why I find the O() notation insanely more useful than limits.

Comment: Well done!  Brute force wins!  This is a very straightforward proof without the need to appeal to a nested set of theorems, each of which requires proof.

Answer (score 29):

This problem can be found in Kaczor, Nowak: Problems in Mathematical Analysis I, Real Numbers, Sequences and Series. I'll copy their solution here.

---

Problem 2.5.22, [p.50](http://books.google.com/books?id=HrO6QzUHU-gC&pg=PA50), a solution is given on [p.215](http://books.google.com/books?id=HrO6QzUHU-gC&pg=PA215).

> **Problem 2.5.22**. The sequence $(a_n)$ is defined inductively as follows:
>   $$0<a_1<\pi \qquad a_{n+1}=\sin a_n \text{ for }n\ge 1$$
>   Prove that 
>   $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt n a_n = \sqrt3$.

*Solution:*
It is easy to see that the sequence $(a_n)$ is monotonically
decreasing to zero. Moreover, an application of I'Hospital's rule gives
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2-\sin^2x}{x^2\sin^2x}=\frac13.$$
Therefore
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1{a_{n+1}^2}-\frac1{a_n^2}\right)=\frac13$$
Now, by the result in Problem 2.3.14, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} na_n^2 = 3$.

---

Problem 2.3.14, 
[p.38](http://books.google.com/books?id=HrO6QzUHU-gC&pg=PA38), a solution is given on [p.184](http://books.google.com/books?id=HrO6QzUHU-gC&pg=PA184).

> **Problem 2.3.14.** Prove that if $(a_n)$ is a sequence for which
>   $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)=a$$
>   then
>   $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}n=a.$$

Solution: In [Stolz theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) we set $x_{n}=a_{n+1}$ and $y_n=n$.

Formulation of Stolz theorem [in this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=HrO6QzUHU-gC&pg=PA37) is the following

> Let $(x_n)$, $(y_n)$ be two sequences that satisfy the conditions:
>
> - $(y_n)$ strictly increases to $+\infty$,
> - $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n-x_{n-1}}{y_n-y_{n-1}}=g.$$
>
> Then $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n}{y_n}=g.$$

For Stolz-Cesaro theorem see also this question: [Stolz-Cesàro Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109069/stolz-cesaro-theorem)

Perhaps it is also worth mentioning that there are two equivalent forms of Stolz-Cesaro theorem: see e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/100542/).

Comment: Another source: Polya-Szego, Problem and Theorems in analysis I, Spronger-Verlag, problems 173-174, p.38

Comment: .........Thanks!

Comment: Now I noticed that this question also has an answer based on Stolz-Cesaro: [Need help solving Recursive series](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135649/need-help-solving-recursive-series).

Comment: I wish to you all the best :-) I not forgot. Thank you very much ....

Answer (score 4):

If your sequence is of the form
$$x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$$
with
$$f(x) = x( 1 - c x^{\alpha} + \textrm{h. o. t} )$$
then notice ( [e.g.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=TaylorSeries%5B%201%2F%20%28x%281-%20c%20x%5E%281%2F3%29%29%29%5E%281%2F3%29%2C%20%7Bx%2C0%2C3%7D%5D) ) that
$$\frac{1}{f(x)^{\alpha}} = \frac{1}{x^{\alpha}} +  \alpha c+ \textrm{h. o. t.}$$
and so
$$\frac{1}{x_{n+1}^{\alpha}} - \frac{1}{x_n^{\alpha}} \to  \alpha c$$
and with [Cesaro-Stolz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem#Arithmetic_mean) we get
$$\frac{1}{n x_n^{\alpha} } \to  \alpha c$$

In the particular case $f(x) = \sin x= x( 1 - \frac{x^2}{6} + \cdots)$, we get
$$\frac{1}{n x_n^2} \to 2 \cdot \frac{1}{6}  = \frac{1}{3}$$

$\bf{Added}$ We can get effective estimates for the sequence

$x_{n+1} = \sin x_n$ as follows

Consider the Taylor [expansion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=TaylorSeries%5B%283%2F%28Sin%5Bx%5D%29%5E2-%203%2Fx%5E2%20-1%29%2Fx%5E2%2C%20%7Bx%2C%200%2C%204%7D%5D)

$$\frac{\frac{3}{\sin^2 x} - \frac{3}{x^2} - 1}{x^2} = \frac{1}{5} + \frac{2 x^2}{63} + \cdots$$

where all the remaining coefficients are positive. We conclude that for $0<|x|< \pi$ we get

$$\frac{\frac{3}{\sin^2 x} - \frac{3}{x^2} -1}{x^2} > \frac{1}{5}$$

and for $0 < |x|< 1$ we have

$$\frac{\frac{3}{\sin^2 x} - \frac{3}{x^2} -1}{x^2} <  
\frac{\frac{3}{\sin^2 x} - \frac{3}{x^2} -1}{x^2} \ _{x=1}=0.2368\ldots < \frac{1}{4}$$

Therefore we have for $0< |x|\le 1$

$$\frac{3}{x^2} + 1 + \frac{x^2}{5}<\frac{3}{\sin^2 x} < \frac{3}{x^2} + 1 + \frac{x^2}{4}$$

Now for the sequence $y_n= \frac{3}{x_n^2}$ we get the inequalities

$$y_n+ 1 + \frac{3}{5 y_n} < y_{n+1} < y_n + 1 + \frac{3}{4 y_n}$$

and we can use this to get  estimates for $y_n$ and so $x_n$.