# How to find the limit of these sequences?

Tags: calculus, limits, contest-math

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a real-valued sequence such that $a_1 \geq 0$ and $$a_{n+1}=\ln(a_{n}+1)$$ for all $n\ge1$. How can we find the following limits?

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}na_n=?,$$ $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n(na_n-2)}{\ln n}=?$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $a_1 \geq 0$?

Comment: @user17762: yes

Comment: $a_1=0$ is not of your interest.

Comment: Given that you are asked the second question, the answer to the first must be $2$.  Otherwise the second goes to $+\infty$

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit of the sequence $nx\_{n}$ where $x\_{n+1} = \log (1 +x\_{n})$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5408/limit-of-the-sequence-nx-n-where-x-n1-log-1-x-n)

Comment: Oops, cast dupe close vote too quickly. Too many questions in one. The last one is not answered there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use Stolz–Cesàro theorem, it is much easier to get the limit. Note that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. By using Stolz–Cesàro theorem, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\frac{1}{a_n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{a_n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_na_{n+1}}{a_n-a_{n+1}}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n\ln(a_n+1)}{a_n-\ln(a_n+1)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x\ln(x+1)}{x-\ln(x+1)}\\
&=&\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x(x-\frac{1}{2}x^2+O(x^3))}{x-(x-\frac{1}{2}x^2+O(x^3))}\\
&=&2. 
\end{eqnarray*}
Here $\ln(x+1)=x-\frac{1}{2}x^2+O(x^3)$. For the second part, we first note that
$$ a_n=\frac{2}{n}+o(1), \frac{1}{\ln(1+x)}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x}{12}+O(x^2) $$
and hence
\begin{eqnarray*} 
\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}&=&\frac{1}{\ln(1+a_n)}=\frac{1}{a_n}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{12}a_n+O(a_n^2)=\frac{1}{a_n}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{6n}+O(\frac{1}{n^2}).
\end{eqnarray*}
So by using Stolz–Cesàro theorem
\begin{eqnarray*} 
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n(na_n-2)}{\ln n}&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{na_n(na_n-2)}{a_n\ln n}\\
&=&2\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{na_n-2}{a_n\ln n}=4\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{a_n}}{\ln n}\\
&=&4\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\frac{n+1}{2}-\frac{1}{a_{n+1}})-(\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{a_n})}{\ln (n+1)-\ln n}\\
&=&4\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}+\frac{1}{a_n}}{\ln (n+1)-\ln n}\\
&=&4\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{6n}+O(\frac{1}{n^2})}{\ln (n+1)-\ln n}\\
&=&\frac{2}{3}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}\\
&=&\frac{2}{3}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Your answer is correct, I forgot the term $\frac{a^3_n}{3}$ in the taylor series of $\log(1+a_n)$. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 10):

We have 
$$0\leq\log(1+x)\leq x\quad \forall x\geq 0$$
so we can deduce that the sequence $(a_n)$ is decreasing and bounded below by $0$ so it's convergent to $\ell$ which satisfy $\log(1+\ell)=\ell$ so $\ell=0$.

We know that (since $a_n\to 0$) $$a_{n+1}=\log(1+a_n)=a_n-\frac{1}{2}a_n^2+o(a_n^2)$$
hence we have
$$a_{n+1}^\alpha=a_n^\alpha\left(1-\frac{1}{2}a_n+o(a_n)\right)^\alpha\sim_\infty a_n^\alpha\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{2}a_n\right)\tag{1}$$
and if we choose $\alpha=-1$ and by telescoping we find
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{a_{k+1}}-\frac{1}{a_{k}}=\frac{1}{a_{n}}-\frac{1}{a_{1}}\sim_\infty\frac{n}{2}$$
 and therefore we find
$$a_n\sim_\infty\frac{2}{n}$$

Now in the equality $(1)$ and always with $\alpha=-1$ we develop with one term of more:
$$\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{a_{n}}-\frac{1}{2}\sim_\infty\frac{-1}{12} a_n\sim \frac{-1}{6n}$$
so by telescoping we find
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{a_{k+1}}-\frac{1}{a_{k}}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\sim_\infty\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{n}{2}\sim_\infty \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{2}{k}\sim_\infty \frac{-1}{6}\log n$$
and finally we find
$$\frac{n(na_n-2)}{\log n}\sim_\infty \frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: i like the $\sim_\infty$ notation, Ive never seen that before.

Comment: @MSEoris It should be used with care, however.

Comment: one upvote away, now, from a nice-answer!

Answer (score 7):

A physisist's approach to the 1st limit (**not proof at all**): first of all it is clear that $a_n\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. The question is - how? Supose that $a_n=a(n)$ can be modeled by a smooth function of $x$. Then, expanding the left side and right side of the recursion relation into Taylor series to "first order", we find the ODE
$$a'(x)=-\frac12a(x)^2$$ 
with the obvious solution $a(x)=\frac{2}{x}$. So a physicist would conclude that  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}na_n=2$.