# Convergence of series involving iterated $ \sin $

Tags: analysis, sequences-and-series

I've been trying to show the convergence or divergence of

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin^n 1}{n} = \frac{\sin 1}{1} + \frac{\sin \sin 1}{2} + \frac{\sin \sin \sin 1}{3} + \ \cdots $$

where the superscript means iteration (*not* multiplication, so it's not simply less than a geometric series -- I couldn't find the standard notation for this).

Problem is,

- $ \sin^n 1 \to 0 $ as $ n \to \infty $ (which I eventually proved by assuming a positive limit and having $ \sin^n 1 $ fall below it, after [getting its existence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem)) helps the series to converge,

but at the same time

- $ \sin^{n+1} 1 = \sin \sin^n 1 \approx \sin^n 1 $ for large $ n $ makes it resemble the divergent harmonic series.

I would appreciate it if someone knows a helpful convergence test or a proof (or any kind of advice, for that matter).

In case it's useful, here are some things I've tried:

- Show $ \sin^n 1 = O(n^{-\epsilon}) $ and use the p-series.  I'm not sure that's even true.
- Computer tests and looking at partial sums.  Unfortunately, $ \sum 1/n $ diverges very slowly, which is hard to distinguish from convergence.
- Somehow work in the related series
  $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos^n 1}{n} = \frac{\cos 1}{1} + \frac{\cos \cos 1}{2} + \frac{\cos \cos \cos 1}{3} + \ \cdots $$
  which I know diverges since the numerators approach a fixed point.

Comment: @Qiaochu: this problem is not a duplicate, it is asking for something much weaker than the other problem, and there may be additional solutions that do not cite the other result. (Not that I know of any, but a suspicion that any solution of this problem has to repeat the other one is not enough to make the question a clone).

Comment: @T..: fair enough.

Comment: Boy do I feel stupid for not noticing the other question.  Sorry.

Comment: You shouldn't feel bad about not seeing the other question.  I don't see any obvious way for you to have searched for it.  In any case, even if were exactly the same question, duplicates are not a big deal.  Duplicates get closed because there is no reason to keep 2 threads open in such cases, not as punishment for offenders.

Comment: See also here (num.U213) https://www.awesomemath.org/wp-content/uploads/reflections/2012_1/MR6solutions.pdf for a proof of the first two terms of the expansion

Comment: Iteration is typically marked as $\sin^{(n)}(1)$ adding it in the comment that it is iteration of the function as it can be confused with n-th derivative. Otherwise... it is very easy to make a confusion of other kind.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A Google search has turned up an analysis of the asymptotic behavior of the iterates of $\sin$ on [page 157](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=_tnwmvHmVwMC&pg=PA157) of de Bruijn's *Asymptotic methods in analysis*.  Namely,

$$\sin^n(1)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{n}}\left(1+O\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n}\right)\right),$$

which implies that your series converges.

Edit: Aryabhata has pointed out in a comment that the problem of showing that $\sqrt{n}\sin^n(1)$ converges to $\sqrt{3}$ already appeared in the question [Convergence of $\sqrt{n}x_{n}$ where $x_{n+1} = \sin(x_{n})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3215) (asked by Aryabhata in August). I had missed or forgot about it.  David Speyer gave a great self contained answer, and he also referenced de Bruijn's book.  De Bruijn gives a reference to a 1945 work of Pólya and Szegő for this result.

Comment: Wow, so apparently even $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin^n 1}{n^{1/2 + \epsilon}} $ would converge.  I've got to wonder:  how do you search for math like that?

Comment: The search was "iterations of sine asymptotic" without quotes, and the Google Books result for page 157 of de Bruijn's book was the first hit.