# Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converge? $ a_1=1,\ a_2=\sin(a_1),\dots, a_n =\sin(a_{n-1}) $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Recently, I came across an interesting problem. I haven't yet managed to solve it, but I really want to find out the solution.

> Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converge?
>   $$
> a_1=1,\ a_2=\sin(a_1),\dots, a_n =\sin(a_{n-1})
> $$

I tried to use inequality $x\geqslant \sin(x)$ and prove by induction that $a_k\geqslant a_{k+1}$, but I didn't succeed.
Anyway, I think that the sequence $\left\{a_k\right\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is monotonically decreasing, and it might be important.
As for the ratio test and the root test, I couldn't apply them here.

Could someone help me?

Comment: $a_k>sin(a_k)=a_{k+1}\ \Rightarrow \ a_k>a_{k+1}$

obviously when $k\rightarrow\ \infty$ , then $a_k=sin(a_k)$ , therefore $a_k $tends to zero.But this all does not mean the series converges.

Comment: It's necessary that the sequence $\{a_k\}$ converges to 0, and it does. Ration test should work to show that the series converges.

Comment: Show that $a_n\to0$, then show that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\left(\frac1{\sin^2(x)}-\frac1{x^2}\right)=\frac13$. Apply [Stolz-Cesàro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) to show that $a_n\sim\sqrt{\frac3n}$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine if this series converges or diverges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2188962/determine-if-this-series-converges-or-diverges) – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Csin%5E%7B(n)%7D(1)%24&p=1)

Comment: @MartinR: Thanks for that link. I will post my answer there.

Comment: Thank you, everyone!