# Stolz-Cesàro Theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Recently I've been trying to find a satisfactory proof of the Stolz-Cesàro Theorem but I havent found any. As I remember the claim is as follows:

Let $${\left\{ {{b_n}} \right\}_{n \in {\Bbb N}}}$$ be a sequence such that

$${b_{k + 1}} - {b_k} > 0  $$ and $$ \mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to \infty }\sum_{n=0}^{k} {b_n} = \infty   $$

Then if $${\left\{ {{a_n}} \right\}_{n \in {\Bbb N}}}$$ is another sequence and the limit

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{{a_{n + 1}} - {a_n}}}{{{b_{n + 1}} - {b_n}}} = \ell_1 $$

exists, then

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{{a_n}}}{{{b_n}}} = {\ell _2}$$

exists too and

$${\ell _1} = {\ell _2}$$

Comment: Since $\displaystyle \frac{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} - 1}{\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} - 1} = \frac{b_n}{a_n} \frac{a_{n+1} - a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}$, this is just restating the original statement, at least if $\ell_1 \ne 0$.  You'd also have to treat the case $\ell_1 = 0$ separately.

Comment: @RobertIsrael But you see I want to show that that expression tends to one. If it is not possible, let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a proof [at planetmath.org](http://planetmath.org/proofofstolzcesarotheorem).

Comment: @Peter: Could you edit your question to explain that you're looking for an approach other than the one given there?

Comment: @ZevChonoles Yes, no problem.

Comment: It seems to me that the final step in that proof is not quite right. But if one writes $$l-2\epsilon < \frac{a_{k+1}}{b_{k+1}} < l+2\epsilon$$ instead, then it should be OK.

Comment: @HansLundmark Can you answer with a corrected proof?

Comment: @Peter: I though I just did... ;-) But since you asked for it, I've written a separate answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Jonas; I'll take care of it when I'm on the real computer instead of the Kindle.

Comment: Please try to describe as much here as possible in order to make the answer self-contained. Links are fine as support, but they can go stale and then an answer which is nothing more than a link loses its value. Please read [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Answer (score 17):

I find it easiest to view this geometrically.
With 
$\ell  - \epsilon  < \frac{{{a_{n + 1}} - {a_n}}}{{{b_{n + 1}} - {b_n}}} < \ell  + \epsilon$
for $n \ge N$,
all the points 
$(x,y)=(b_n,a_n)$
for $n \ge N$ will lie inside the wedge formed by the two lines through
the point $(x,y)=(b_N,a_N)$
with slopes $\ell  - \epsilon$ and $\ell + \epsilon$, respectively.
And this wedge will, for large enough $x$,
stay entirely within the wider wedge formed by the lines
$y = (\ell - 2 \epsilon) x$ and $y = (\ell + 2 \epsilon) x$
through the origin.
(This step is where the PlanetMath proof is not quite precise;
the statement is not necessarily true if you take the lines
$y = (\ell - \epsilon) x$ and $y = (\ell + \epsilon) x$.)
Since $b_n \nearrow +\infty$, all points $(x,y)=(b_n,a_n)$
for $n \ge M$, say, will have large enough $x$ coordinate to lie in the part of the narrower wedge that lies inside the wider wedge; thus
$\ell - 2 \epsilon < \frac{a_n}{b_n} < \ell + 2 \epsilon$ for $n \ge M$.
Done.

Comment: Could you help me out with some graphics? Or a less intuitive approach? Upvoted anyways.

Comment: @Peter: Graphics? I'm afraid that's too much work... Just draw your own picture by hand. It's not exactly difficult: a point, two lines through that point, two other lines through the origin, done. And notice that $(a_{n+1}-a_n)/(b_{n+1}-b_n)$ is the slope of the line segment between two consecutive points $(x,y)=(b_n,a_n)$; since all these segments have slopes between $\ell - \epsilon$ and $\ell + \epsilon$, the whole train of such segments starting at $(b_N,a_N)$ never goes outside of the wedge.

Comment: How do you know, tht for sufficently big x, the point will not be with in the the triangle, of $y=(l\pm \epsilon) x$ but in $2\epsilon$ religion?

Comment: @MDesmond: I'm not sure I understand your question. (Even if I replace the word “religion” with “region”!) Could you try to be more precise?

Comment: "$y = (\ell - \epsilon) x$ and $y = (\ell + \epsilon) x$.)
Since $b_n \nearrow +\infty$, all points $(x,y)=(b_n,a_n)$
for $n \ge M$, say, will have large enough $x$ coordinate to lie in the part of narrower wedge."  So whats wrong with that? Why again consider $(\ell +2\epsilon , \ell+2 \epsilon) $ ?

Comment: @MDesmond: Suppose, for example, that $(b_N,a_N)$ lies above the wedge $$W_1 = \{ (x,y) : (\ell-\epsilon) x < y < (\ell+\epsilon)x \}$$ and that all the points $(b_n,a_n)$ for $n \ge N$ lie along the straight line through $(b_N,a_N)$ of slope $\ell+\epsilon$. Then none of them will lie in $W_1$. But they will (for large all enough $n$) lie inside the wider wedge $$W_2 = \{ (x,y) : (\ell-2\epsilon) x < y < (\ell+2\epsilon)x \},$$ since the line $y=(\ell+2 \epsilon)x$ will eventually overtake any line of the form $y=(\ell+\epsilon) x + C$.

Answer (score 17):

Here's a more general situation:

**THM** Let $\langle a_n\rangle$ be any sequence of real numbers and suppose that $\langle b_n\rangle $ is a sequence of positive numbers such that $b_n$ is strictly monotone increasing to $\infty$. Then $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}\geq \liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}$$ $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}\leq \limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}$$

**PROOF** We prove the case for $\liminf$; the $\limsup$ case is analogous. Take $$\alpha <\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}$$

Then there exists $N$ such that for each $k\geq 0$ we have $$\alpha <\frac{a_{N+k}-a_{N+k-1}}{b_{N+k}-b_{N+k-1}}$$ Since $b_{n+1}>b_n$, we have for $k\geq 0$ that
$$\alpha \left( {{b_{N + k}} - {b_{N + k - 1}}} \right) < {a_{N + k}} - {a_{N + k - 1}}$$

Thus, for any $m\geq 0$, $$\eqalign{
   \alpha \sum\limits_{k = 0}^m {\left( {{b_{N + k}} - {b_{N + k - 1}}} \right)} & < \sum\limits_{k = 0}^m {\left( {{a_{N + k}} - {a_{N + k - 1}}} \right)}   \cr 
   \alpha \left( {{b_{N + m}} - {b_{N - 1}}} \right) &< {a_{N + m}} - {a_{N - 1}} \cr} $$

It follows that $$\alpha \left( {1 - \frac{{{b_{N - 1}}}}{{{b_{N + m}}}}} \right) < \frac{{{a_{N + m}}}}{{{b_{N + m}}}} - \frac{{{a_{N - 1}}}}{{{b_{N + m}}}}$$ and taking $m\to\infty$ $$\alpha  \leq \mathop {\lim \inf }\limits_{m \to \infty } \frac{{{a_m}}}{{{b_m}}}$$

It follows that, for each $\alpha <\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}$ we have $\alpha  \leq \liminf\limits_{m \to \infty } \dfrac{{{a_m}}}{{{b_m}}}$, which means $$\mathop {\liminf }\limits_{n \to \infty } \dfrac{{{a_{n + 1}} - {a_n}}}{{{b_{n + 1}} - {b_n}}} \leq  \liminf\limits_{m\to\infty} \frac{{{a_m}}}{{{b_m}}}$$

**COR** Let $\langle a_n\rangle$ and $\langle b_n\rangle$ be as before. Then if $$\ell=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}$$ exists, so does  $$\ell'=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}$$ and $\ell=\ell'$

**COR** Let $x_n$ be any sequence. If $$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=\ell$$ then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^n x_k=\ell$$

**P** By the first corollary with $b_n=n$ and $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n x_k$, we have $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n + 1} {{a_k}}  - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {{a_k}} }}{{n + 1 - n}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {x_{n + 1}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {x_n}$$

which means $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{{a_n}}}{{{b_n}}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {{x_k}}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {x_n}$$

Comment: just wondering if lim am/bm = $\alpha$, shouldn't $\lim \frac{a_{n+1} - a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}$ > $\lim \frac{a_m}{b_m}$

Comment: referring to the line before the first corollary. I don't really understand how the conclusion is arrived

Comment: Are you assuming in this proof that $(b_n)$ diverges to infinity?

Comment: @user84413 I have clarified it.

Comment: Thanks, Pedro, and thanks for the proof as well as the corollaries.