# Mean of the terms of convergent sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Consider a convergent sequence  $a_1,a_2,a_3\cdots a_n$ tending to a limit A. Now consider the sequence $K_1,K_2,K_3 \cdots K_n$ such that $K_n =\cfrac {a_1+a_2+...a_n}n$.
Now what I guess is that as an tends to infinity $K_n$ tends to $a_n$.
 What I can say is that the sequence $K_n$ is a bounded one. As such it must have a convergent sub sequence. Is this sequence also convergent.

I tried to resolve this by first trying to apply squeeze theorem as $K_n$ always lies between the minimum and maximum of that sequence. But I could not meet up rigor or any clear result.

Next I tried to apply Cauchy's principle, but here I don't think that one can reach to a strong consequence except few suggestive apprehensions.

I hope someone can guide me on this problem with a proof.

Comment: Moyenne de Cesàro.

Comment: See also: [Prove convergence of a sequence](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207910/).
There and in linked questions several proofs (or several versions of the same proof) can be found. AFAIK the proofs I've seen are not similar to the proof of [Stolz-Cesaro Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem). 
The question [limit of quotient of two
series](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100338/) has
relatively detailed proof of Stolz-Cesaro, also the question [Stolz-Cesaro Theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109069/) has
several links.

Answer (score 3):

This is the [Cesàro mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean), which is the basis of [Cesàro summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation). A proof that it preserves convergence is found e.g. [here](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/sequence/hardlim/hardlim.html) (second example).

Answer (score 0):

Limit of K(n) as n tends to infinity Is 'a' the limit of sequence a(n)

Comment: They only coincide when $a_n$ is a convergent sequence. But $K_n$ can converge even though $a_n$ doesn't converge. Take for example $a_n=(-1)^n$, then $|K_n| \leq \frac{1}{n}$ and hence $K_n$ converges $0$.