# Proving $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}=L$ implies $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=L$

Tags: analysis, limits

Suppose $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are sequences where $b_n$ is increasing and approaching positive infinity. Assume that $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ $\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}=L$, where $L$ is a real number. Prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ $\frac{a_n}{b_n}=L$.

Comment: A hint: consider an epsilon-delta definition of the first limit and ask what you can say about $\dfrac{a_{n+k}-a_n}{b_{n+k}-b_n}$ for sufficiently large $n$ and some fixed $k$ based on that; then 'flip it on its head' and find an epsilon-delta estimate for $\dfrac{a_{n+k}}{b_{n+k}}$ as $k\to\infty$ starting with some fixed $n$.

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a\le b$ imply $a+c\le b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* I've done so for you now.

Comment: @Lord_Farin You realize that the OP last (and probably first) visited the site on Nov 15 '12?

Comment: @Did Hm... I must have been put off by the fact that the question showed up on the main page. Oh well, it can't hurt to retain the comment, I suppose.

Comment: Wikipedia: [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem). See also: [limit of quotient of two series](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/100338) and [Stolz-Cesàro Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/109069).

Answer (score 3):

This result is known as "Stolz-Cesaro theorem". See here for the [proof](https://planetmath.org/ProofOfStolzCesaroTheorem).