# One simple limit which i need to prove

Tags: calculus

I need to prove that, it's clearly obvius, but i dont know how to prove that:

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}n^\frac 1n = 1 $$

Comment: Have you studied L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: yes, but i would like to solve that in a different way

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115822/lim-n-to-infty-n-frac1n).

Answer (score 2):

Note that $n^{1/n} \geq 1$ for $n\geq 1$ so there is a sequence of non-negative reals $\delta(n)$ s.t. $n^{1/n} = 1 + \delta (n)$ for each $n$. Show that $\delta(n) \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ by raising both sides to the power of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Explicit solution is given in the other answers.

But, it is worth noting that the discrete version of L'Hospital theorem is [Stolz-Cesaro theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) (with explicit solution [here](http://books.google.ca/books?id=5iK9OX9z014C&pg=PA85&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109069/stolz-cesaro-theorem)).

In it, take $a_n = \ln n$ and $b_n=n$. Check its conditions and apply it. This will give you $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\ln n}{n} = 0.$$ Imply the limit you need from this.