# Show that $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{\sum^n x_i}{\sum^n y_i}=a.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Let $\{y_n\}$ a sequence so that $\sum y_i=+\infty$ and
$$y_n>0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$$

Show that if 
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{x_n}{y_n}=a$$
then
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{\displaystyle \sum^n x_i}{\displaystyle \sum^n y_i}=a.$$

Comment: Isn't this more or less the same as this question: [Stolz-Cesàro Theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109069/stolz-cesàro-theorem) (applied to the partial sums) ?

Comment: I'm tryng to do $-\varepsilon+a<\frac{x_n}{y_n}<\varepsilon+a$ and to applie the partial sums.

Comment: @MartinR I need to do without using this property...

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Without what property? If you set $a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n x_k$ and $b_n = \sum_{k=1}^n y_k$ then you can directly apply the proofs given in the thread that I linked to.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\epsilon >0$. Then there exists some $N$ so that for all $n > N$ we have

$$\left| \frac{x_n}{y_n} -a \right|<\epsilon$$

Therefore

$$\left| x_n -ay_n\right| < \epsilon y_n \,.$$

As $y_n$ is positive, it follows that 
$$\sum_{i=N}^n \left| x_i -ay_i\right| \leq \sum_{i=N}^n \epsilon y_i \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon y_i= | \sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon y_i| (*)$$

Therefore, for all $n >N$ we have

$$\left|\frac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n  y_i}-a \right| \leq\left|\frac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N x_i}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n  y_i} \right|+ \left|\frac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=N}^n x_i}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n  y_i}-a \right|\\
=\left|\frac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N x_i}{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n  y_i} \right|+ \left|\frac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=N}^n x_i-\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n a
y_i}{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n  y_i} \right| \\
\leq \left|\frac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N x_i}{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n  y_i} \right|+ \left|\frac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=N}^n (x_i- a
y_i)}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n  y_i} \right|+\left|\frac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N  a
y_i}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n  y_i} \right|$$

Now  $(*)$ tells us that the middle term is $<\epsilon$.

Since **$N$ is fixed**, and $\sum y_n \to \infty$ it is easy to prove that

$$\lim_n\frac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N x_i}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n  y_i} = \lim_n \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N  a
y_i}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n  y_i}  =0$$

Therefore, you can find some $N_1$ so that for all $n >N_1$ the first and third term in the above inequality are less that $\epsilon$. This completes the proof.