# Inverting a fraction in a limit

Tags: limits

I've seen in a limit problem(limit of a fraction) that the fraction can be inverted and then proceed on the new fraction. Is this ok? Can someone show a proof?

Comment: Could you give an example of what exactly happens?

Comment: Here in the answer of Marcus Scheuer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1137451/how-to-understand-intuitively-the-stolz-cesaro-theorem-for-sequences

Comment: But he inverts the limits he finds as well; that's a consequence of a property (see below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have:
$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$$
with $L \ne 0$, then you also have:
$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{1}{f(x)} = \frac{1}{L}$$
So yes: you can consider the inverted fraction, but then you get the reciprocal of the (non-zero) limit as well.

Comment: Reference and proof to this?

Comment: @LearningMath Continuity of $1/x$ isn't enough?

Comment: @LearningMath Most calculus texts cover this and some related questions on this site; do a search on *reciprocal (rule)*. You can find a proof of the main limit laws, including this one, on [this site](http://www.milefoot.com/math/calculus/limits/GenericLimitLawProofs04.htm).

Comment: +1. Note this is a consequence of the following. If $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) = L$ and $g$ is continuous at $L$, then $\lim\limits_{x \to a} g(f(x)) = g(L)$. In your case, you are taking $g(x) = 1/x$ so $g$ is continuous there as long as $L\neq 0$.