# Finding $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n^2]{a_n}$ given that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n a_{n+2}}{(a_{n+1})^2}=L^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

This is the problem I saw in [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2823471) - which was later [closed and deleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2823471/revisions) (the close reason was missing context). Still, the problem seemed interesting to me - at least in the sense that the solution is not immediately obvious.

The problem:

> Suppose that $(a_n)$ is a real sequence such that $a_n>0$ for $n>0$ and
>   $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_na_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}^2}=L^2.$$
>   Suppose further that $L\ge0$
>   Find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n^2]{a_n}$. (In terms of $L$.)

The original problem in the linked question was given with $L=2$. However, I do not think that the problem should change that much for any value of $L$. (Maybe one could be suspicious about $L=0$?)

It is also clear - at least for $L>0$ - that *if* it is possible to express the second limit using $L$, then the limit should be equal to $L$. It suffices to notice that for $a_n = L^{n^2}$ we have
$$\frac{a_na_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}^2}=
\frac{L^{n^2+(n+2)^2}}{L^{2(n+1)^2}} =
L^{(2n^2+4n+4)-2(n^2+2n+2)} = L^2.
$$

So we know what is the candidate for the result, we still need to prove whether this is actually true.

I have posted my attempt as answer. But I will be glad to learn about other solutions. (And of course, also corrections to my approach, if I made some mistakes.)

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of simplicity, let us assume that $L>0$. And later we will check what has to be modified in the case $L=0$.

Let us denote $b_n = \frac{\log a_n}{\log L}$. (I.e., the logarithm at the base $L$.) Then the limit
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_na_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}^2}=L^2$$
changes to
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (b_{n+2}-2b_{n+1}+b_n) = 2.$$
And if we put $c_n=b_{n+1}-b_n$ then we have
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (c_{n+1}-c_n)=2.$$
Applying Stolz-Cesaro theorem<sup>1</sup> twice we get
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{b_{n+1}-b_n}n = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{c_n}n =2$$
and
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{b_n}{\frac{n(n-1)}2}=2.$$

Therefore we get
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{b_n}{n(n-1)}=1 \qquad\text{and}\qquad \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{b_n}{n^2} = 1.$$
So we have
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log{a_n}}{n^2\log L} = \frac{\log{\sqrt[n^2]{a_n}}}{\log L}=1$$ 
i.e. 
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \log \sqrt[n^2]{a_n}=\log L \qquad\text{and}\qquad \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n^2]{a_n}=L.$$

---

What happens if $L=0$? Already the first step does make sense, since we cannot take logarithm of $L^2=0$.

Let us now take $b_n=\log a_n$. (To avoid $\log L$ in denominator-- which was there just to simplify the numbers we work with, so that we do not have to write $\log L$ every time.)

In the first step we have just used that $x_n\to L$ implies $\log x_n\to\log L$. If we have $x_n\to0^+$, we still have $\log x_n\to -\infty$. So for $b_n=\log a_n$ we $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (b_{n+2}-2b_{n+1}+b_n) = -\infty$.

Stolz-Cesaro theorem is true also for $\pm\infty$. Which means that the following steps are correct if we replace $2$ by $-\infty$.

Finally we arrive at $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \log \sqrt[n^2]{a_n}=-\infty$, which gives us 
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n^2]{a_n}=0$$
simply by using that $\log x_n\to-\infty$ implies $x_n\to0^+$.

Which means that the same result is true for $L=0$.

---

<sup>1</sup>See Wikipedia: [Stolz–Cesaro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem). Some proofs of this result can be found [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/109069).

Comment: Just one doubt. The question was asked 3 Minutes ago. And you posted such a long answer 3 minutes ago. How is this even possible?

Comment: @user567182 It is possible to post a question and an answer *at the same time.* This feature was mentioned on meta around the time when it was introduced: [Recently rolled out SE Encyclopedia feature.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4286) In which situations it is suitable is another question - but it is definitely encouraged that the poster shows their own attempts when posting the question, posting self-answer might be a way to do this. If you are interested in other past discussions about this, you might have a look at posts tagged ([meta-tag:self-answer]) on meta.

Comment: Perfect answer. +1 I had mentioned the same approach in comments to the original (now closed deleted question).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer that I posted to the question mentioned in this question, but deleted almost immediately due to the lack of context in that question.

---

If
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n\,a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}^2}=L^2\tag1
$$
then for any $\epsilon\gt0$, there is an $N_\epsilon$ so that for $n\ge N_\epsilon$,
$$
\left|\,\log\left(\frac{a_n\,a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}^2}\right)-2\log(L)\,\right|\le\epsilon\tag2
$$
Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\log\left(\frac{a_j\,a_{j+2}}{a_{j+1}^2}\right)
&=\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\log\left(\frac{a_0}{a_k}\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_1}\right)\\
&=\frac1n\log\left(\frac{a_0}{a_1}\right)+\frac1{n^2}\log\left(\frac{a_n}{a_0}\right)\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Inspired by the following diagram

[image]

We can break down the sum on the left side of $(3)$ as follows
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\log\left(\frac{a_j\,a_{j+2}}{a_{j+1}^2}\right)
&=\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=N_\epsilon}^{n-1}\sum_{j=N_\epsilon}^{k-1}\overbrace{\log\left(\frac{a_j\,a_{j+2}}{a_{j+1}^2}\right)}^\text{within $\epsilon$ of $2\log(L)$}\\
&\color{#C00}{+\frac{n-N_\epsilon}{n^2}\sum_{j=0}^{N_\epsilon-1}\log\left(\frac{a_j\,a_{j+2}}{a_{j+1}^2}\right)+\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=0}^{N_\epsilon-1}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\log\left(\frac{a_j\,a_{j+2}}{a_{j+1}^2}\right)}\tag4
\end{align}
$$
For any $\epsilon\gt0$, the red terms vanish as $n\to\infty$. The remaining term on the right hand side is $\frac1{n^2}$ times a sum of $\frac{(n-N_\epsilon)^2+(n-N_\epsilon)}2$ terms, all within $\epsilon$ of $2\log(L)$.

Therefore,
$$
\left|\,\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\log\left(\frac{a_n\,a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}^2}\right)-\log(L)\,\right|\le\frac\epsilon2\tag5
$$
Since $(5)$ is true for any $\epsilon\gt0$, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\log\left(\frac{a_n\,a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}^2}\right)=\log(L)\tag6
$$
Taking the limit of the right hand side of $(3)$ as $n\to\infty$, we get
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(a_n)}{n^2}=\log(L)\tag7
$$
which implies
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n^2]{a_n}=L\tag8
$$

Comment: It's great that you posted your answer here. By the time I saw your answer (to the old deleted question) it was in deleted state. +1

Comment: Not surprising, since it was only there for 18 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

This is not another solution, but is the essence of your solution worked out by me individually.

If $L>0$,

By two applications of Stolz-Cesaro theorem,

\begin{align*}
   \lim_{n\to\infty}{{\ln a_n}\over{n^2}}
   &=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\ln{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}}\over{2n+1}}\\
   &=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{n\to\infty}{\ln{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}}\over{n}}\\
   &=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{n\to\infty}{\ln{\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}}-\ln{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}}}\over1}\\
   &=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\Bigg(\frac{\big(\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}}\big)}{\big(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\big)}\Bigg)\\
   &=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\frac{a_na_{n+2}}{{a_{n+1}}^2}\\
   &=\frac{1}{2}\ln(L^2)\\
   &=\ln L\\
   \therefore\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n^2]{a_n}&=L
\end{align*}

If $L=0$,
\begin{align*}
   \lim_{n\to\infty}{{\ln a_n}\over{n^2}}
   &=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\ln{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}}\over{2n+1}}\\
   &=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\ln{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}}\over{n}}\\
   &=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\ln{\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}}-\ln{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}}}\over1}\\
   &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\Bigg(\frac{\big(\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}}\big)}{\big(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\big)}\Bigg)\\
   &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\frac{a_na_{n+2}}{{a_{n+1}}^2}\\
   &=-\infty\\
   \therefore\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n^2]{a_n}&=0
\end{align*}