# prove that $\varlimsup_{n \to \infty} y_n \leq \varlimsup_{n \to \infty} x_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$x_n$ is a bounded number sequence and
I have a sequence where $y_n = \frac{1}{n}(x_1 + .... + x_n), n \in \mathbb{N}$

I need to prove that $\varlimsup_{n \to \infty} y_n \leq \varlimsup_{n \to \infty} x_n$

Can anybody help me with the proof?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/393926/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/411588/42969

Comment: I think in the title those limits should be on $n$, not $x$.

Comment: Yes, thank you, fixed it now