# If $\sigma_n=\frac{s_1+s_2+\cdots+s_n}{n}$ then $\operatorname{{lim sup}}\sigma_n \leq \operatorname{lim sup} s_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

This is a question from the book *Methods of Real Analysis* by R. R. Goldberg.

> If $(s_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers and if $$\sigma_n=\frac{s_1+s_2+\cdots+s_n}{n}$$ then prove that: $\operatorname{{lim sup}}\sigma_n \leq \operatorname{lim sup} s_n$.

I don't have any idea how to start working on this problem. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: well, you may consider that  $\sup \sigma_n \leq \sup \ s_n$ for all n

Comment: @Mathematics: How shall I prove that? And how will it help in this problem? Please explain.

Comment: Assume the opposite, that there is some $k$ with $\operatorname{lim sup} s_n \lt k \lt \operatorname{lim  sup}\sigma_n$, and find a contradiction

Comment: ${\sigma_n = \frac{s_1+s_2+\cdots+s_n}{n}} \le \frac{n(\sup s_n)}{n}$   and take $\lim$ on both side.

Comment: This is a consequence of Stolz-Cesaro theorem, see e.g. [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/100542/8297).

Comment: @Mathematics This only proves the strictly weaker inequality $$\limsup_n\sigma_n\leqslant\sup_ns_n.$$

Comment: @Jack Why do you think that ([tag:limsup]) and ([tag:inequality]) tag are not suitable for this question?

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Rolled back. Those two should be relevant while `means` is not.

Comment: @Jack Thanks for the rollback and also for your attention to tags. I agree that (means) is questionable here. Feel free to ping me here or [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2017/7/6) if you think that these tag-related comments are no longer needed and should be removed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Fix an integer $k$. Let $n\geqslant k$. Then 
$$\sigma_n=\frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^ks_j+\frac 1n\sum_{j=k+1}^ns_j\leqslant \frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^ks_j+\frac{n-k}n\sup_{l\geqslant k}s_l.$$
Now take on both sides the limsup when $\color{red}{n\to +\infty}$: we get the wanted result.

Taking $s_n:=(-1)^n$, we can see that the inequality may not be an equality.

Comment: Can you prove it like this: ${\sigma_n = \frac{s_1+s_2+\cdots+s_n}{n}} \le \frac{n(\sup s_n)}{n}$ and take lim on both sides ? This seems easier to me, but it seems to easy to be right.

Comment: Where do you take the supremum?

Comment: @Kasper This only proves the strictly weaker inequality $$\limsup_n\sigma_n\leqslant\sup_ns_n.$$

Comment: [Another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1049869/limsup-of-average-smaller-than-limsup) asking for clarification for this answer was posted. (I tried to answer it, but in any case I thought it would be polite to leave you a ping. Maybe you will have something to say to the OP of the other question, too.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for pinging.

Comment: The last inequality in your chain holds only if   $\sup_{l\geqslant k}s_l$ is non-negative, as was pointed out in this [request for clarification](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3416895/42969). You can simply omit it.

Comment: @MartinR You are right. I suppressed the last inequality.

Comment: Doesn't this only show that $\limsup \sigma_n \leq \sup_n s_n$

I think there should be one more step where $\forall\varepsilon > 0, \exists N, n\geq N \Rightarrow s_n< M+\varepsilon$. where $M = \limsup s_n$. 

then you'll have $\sigma_n < \dfrac{k}{n} + \dfrac{n - N + 1}{n} (M + \varepsilon)$.

taking limsup on both sides, $\limsup \sigma_n \leq M + \varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, we have the desired result

Comment: @SaadHaider No, because in the upper bound, the supremum is restricted to $l\geqslant k$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Yes, but $\sup_{n\geq k} s_n$ is still just a constant. Your final equation above can be rewritten as $\sigma_n \leq \dfrac{c_1}n + \sup_{n\geq k} s_n - \dfrac{c_3}n$

taking limsup on both sides gives us $\limsup \sigma_n \leq \limsup (\sup_{n\geq k} s_n) = \sup_{n\geq k}$

Comment: Because I see no difference in what you said and what @Kasper said, since what he did is just fix k to be 1

Answer (score 2):

[I've been working through Goldberg myself and found this question looking for an explanation myself. I think I eventually figured it out.]

Since this is from Goldberg, I'll point out that the problem statement suggests using his Theorem 2.9L, which essentially uses the interpretation in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_inferior_and_limit_superior#Interpretation) as an alternate *definition* of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$:

1. $\limsup_{n\to \infty} s_n = M$ means for any $\epsilon > 0$, (a) $s_n < M + \epsilon$ for all but a finite number of values of $n$; (b) $s_n > M - \epsilon$ for infinitely many values of $n$
2. (omitted similar def. for $\liminf$).

(He mentions it's an if and only if relationship, while only proving the "if" direction.)

If you peek ahead a bit to 2.11B, Goldberg happens to prove some things about Cesàro summability $(C,1)$, and you get very close to the desired proof because he uses the same technique he hinted at in this problem.

For the particular problem, by his alternate definition, for some $N_0$, $s_n < M + \epsilon$ if $n > N_0$ (and similarly, for some $N_1$, all $s_n < M + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ if $n > N_1$).

Can we get $\sigma_n$ to eventually fit below $M + \epsilon$ too?

Proceeding as in the accepted answer and splitting the sum into two, the ultimately goal becomes finding a large enough $N_2$ such that $\sigma_n$ (which equals the sum of those two sums) is also smaller than $M + \epsilon$ (for arbitrary $\epsilon$ and all $n > N_2$).

An image may help motivate this:
[image: An image]

The intuition is to "leave some room" between $M + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $M + \epsilon$ such that the sum of the portions for the lower-indexed $s_i$ in $\sigma_n$ can be balanced out in some portion of the $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$-high strip extending from $N_1$ out to infinity.

(Here I'm thinking of the discrete sums as analogous to areas: can the area before $N_1$ fit into the area between $M+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $M+\epsilon$? The answer seems pretty clearly yes to me based on the picture, but I still have to demonstrate the existence of some $N_2$ that works.)

The following reasoning seems to work (at least if $M \ge 0$, which can probably be made more rigorous for by translating each term of the sequence up by a well chosen constant and then undoing that later):

\begin{align}
\sigma_n &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{N_1}s_i + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=N_1+1}^n s_i \\\\
 &\le \frac{N_1}{n}\max_{1\le i\le N_1}|s_i| + \frac{n-N_1}{n}(M + \frac{\epsilon}{2}) \\\\
 &= M + \frac{\epsilon}{2} - \frac{N_1}{n}(M + \frac{\epsilon}{2}) + \frac{N_1}{n}\max_{1\le i\le N_1}|s_i|
\end{align}

Doing some messy math we want to get the sum of the last two terms to be less than $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ so that the whole $\sigma_n \le M + \epsilon$ (and therefore $\limsup_{n\to \infty} \sigma_n \le M$). Any $n \ge N_2 = \lceil\frac{2N_1}{\epsilon}(\max_{1\le i\le N_1}|s_i| - M - \frac{\epsilon}{2})\rceil$ seems to fit the bill.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution:

Let $x^{*}_k = \sup_{k \geq n} \{x_n\}$. Then, $$x^{*}_k \to \limsup_{n \to \infty} \{x_n\}.$$

By a simple fact, a convergent sequence's averages converge to the same limit, so $$\sigma_n^{*} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} x^{*}_j \to \limsup_{n \to \infty} \{x_n\}$$ as well. Now since $\sigma_n \leq \sigma^{*}_n$, the result follows.

Comment: That “simple fact” is the Cesàro summation and – unless I am mistaken – a *consequence* of the inequality to be shown here. So this looks like a circular reasoning to me.