# Show that $\liminf a_n \le \liminf s_n$

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Let $a_1, a_2, a_3,\dotsc$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers. Define
$s_n =\frac{(a_1 + a_2 + ...+ a_n)}{n}$,   $n \in \mathbb{N}$
Show that $\liminf a_n \le \liminf s_n$

---

Can I get some help? I am totally stuck on it.

Comment: This is almost the same question as this one: [If $\sigma_n=\frac{s_1+s_2+\cdots+s_n}{n}$ then $\operatorname{{lim sup}}\sigma_n \leq \operatorname{lim sup} s_n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193157/if-sigma-n-fracs-1s-2-cdotss-nn-then-operatornamelim-sup-sigma).