# show that $ \liminf A \lt \liminf B$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

This is [Exercise 12.12 in the Ross textbook](http://books.google.com/books?id=5JxHZNpMq3AC&pg=PA79&dq=Exercise+12.12+analysis++Ross+textbook&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hVf7UfiHDuS34AS-nIAw&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Exercise%2012.12%20analysis%20%20Ross%20textbook&f=false)

[image]

and I found the solution like the below, but I'm not sure how the yellow line is resulted from the above lines. Can you help me understand this solution please?

[image]

Comment: See also: [If $\sigma_n=\frac{s_1+s_2+\cdots+s_n}{n}$ then $\operatorname{{lim sup}}\sigma_n \leq \operatorname{lim sup} s_n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193157/if-sigma-n-fracs-1s-2-cdotss-nn-then-operatornamelim-sup-sigma). (But I don't think this should be closed as duplicate, because this one asks about a step in the proof of this.)

Answer (score 2):

That is why it is always better to include more words. Consider the sequence defined by $v_n=\inf\{s_k:k>n\}$. Note that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}v_n=\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}s_n$. Now, fix $N>0$, then take $M>N$. Whenever $n>M$ we will have that

$$\begin{align}\sigma_n&=\frac 1 n\left(s_1+\cdots+s_N+s_{N+1}\cdots+s_M+\cdots+s_n\right)\\&=\frac{1}{n}(s_1+\cdots+s_N)+\frac 1 n(s_{N+1}+\cdots+s_{M}+\cdots s_n)\\&\geq\frac{1}{n}(s_1+\cdots+s_N)+\frac{1}{n}(v_N+\cdots+v_N+\cdots +v_N)\\&=\frac 1 n(s_1+\cdots+s_N)+\frac{N-n}{n}v_N\end{align}$$

Since $N$ is *fixed* we will have, by taking $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}$ that $$\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}\sigma_n\geq v_N$$ for each $N>0$. This means $$\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}\sigma_n\geq \liminf_{n\to\infty }s_n=\lim_{N\to\infty }v_N$$