# Question about Answer to limsup of $\sigma_n=\frac{s_1+s_2+\cdots+s_n}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

here's the relevant question: [If $\sigma_n=\frac{s_1+s_2+\cdots+s_n}{n}$ then $\operatorname{{lim sup}}\sigma_n \leq \operatorname{lim sup} s_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/193157/716946)

In the accepted answer, **doesn't the last inequality only work if $\sup_{l\geq k}s_l$ is nonnegative?**
The "last inequality" I'm referring to is this:
$$\frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^ks_j+\frac{n-k}n\sup_{l\geqslant k}s_l\leqslant  \frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^ks_j+\sup_{l\geqslant k}s_l.$$

I ran into this issue when trying to prove the analagous statement for liminf, because in the case of liminf I could only get a similar inequality if $\inf_{l\geq k}s_l \leq 0$, as follows:

$$\sigma_n=
\frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^ks_j+\frac 1n\sum_{j=k+1}^ns_j
\geqslant \frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^ks_j+\frac{n-k}n\inf_{l\geqslant k}s_l
$$
From here, if $\inf_{l\geq k}s_l \leq 0$ then I could continue and write 
$\geq\frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^ks_j+\inf_{l\geqslant k}s_l$.

Could someone clarify please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that
$$ \tag{*}
\sigma_n\geqslant \frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^ks_j+\frac{n-k}n\inf_{l\geqslant k}s_l
$$
and you are right that this is  $\ge \frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^ks_j+\inf_{l\geqslant k}s_l$ only if $\inf_{l\geqslant k}s_l \le  0$.

But that estimate is actually not needed: For fixed $k$  you can take the $\liminf_{n \to \infty}$ in $(*)$, this gives
$$
\liminf_{n \to \infty}\sigma_n\geqslant \inf_{l\geqslant k}s_l
$$
because the right-hand side has a limit for $n \to \infty$.
Then take the limit for $k \to \infty$ and conclude that
$$
\liminf_{n \to \infty}\sigma_n\geqslant\liminf_{n \to \infty}s_n\, .
$$

The same approach works for $\limsup$ in the referenced Q&A.

Comment: When taking $\liminf_{n\to\infty}$ for fixed $k$, we are basically treating each side as a sequence indexed by $n$, and then using the result that if $b_n\geq a_n$ then $\liminf_{n\to\infty}b_n\geq \liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n$, right?

Comment: @lilyboo: Yes, exactly.

Comment: Do we also need to use the result that $\liminf (a_n+b_n)\geq\liminf a_n + \liminf b_n$? That way $\frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^ks_j$ converges to 0 as $n\to\infty$ and also $\liminf_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n-k}n\inf_{l\geqslant k}s_l\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n-k}n\inf_{l\geqslant k}s_l\right)=\inf_{l\geqslant k}s_l\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n-k}n \right)=\inf_{l\geqslant k}s_l$.

Comment: @lilyboo: You don't need that here because the *limit* $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(  \frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^ks_j+\frac{n-k}n\inf_{l\geqslant k}s_l \right)$ exists (and is equal to $\inf_{l\geqslant k}s_l$). Therefore the lim inf of the RHS is equal to that limit.

Comment: And that limit is equal to $\inf_{l\geq k}s_l$ by using some simple limit laws. I see. Thank you!

Comment: Also I think you have a small typo. Shouldn't the first $<$ in the line after $(*)$ be $>$ instead?

Comment: @lilyboo: Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
&\limsup_{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k}s_{j}+\dfrac{n-k}{n}\sup_{l\geq k}s_{l}\right)\\
&\leq\limsup_{n}\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k}s_{j}+\limsup_{n}\dfrac{n-k}{n}\sup_{l\geq k}s_{l}\\
&=\lim_{n}\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k}s_{j}+\lim_{n}\dfrac{n-k}{n}\sup_{l\geq k}s_{l}\\
&=\sup_{l\geq k}s_{l},
\end{align*}
you still got it.