# Limsup of average of a function less than limsup of function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. I would like to show the following:
\begin{equation}
  \limsup_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}\lvert f(\tau)\rvert\,\mathrm{d}\tau\leq
  \limsup_{t\to\infty}\,\lvert f(t)\rvert.
\end{equation}
In this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1049869/limsup-of-average-smaller-than-limsup), an answer is provided in terms of sequences. Does the same ''strategy'' work here as well?

Following these arguments, we have for $0< s\leq t$,
\begin{align}
  \frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}\lvert f(\tau)\rvert\,\mathrm{d}\tau&=
  \frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{s}\lvert f(\tau)\rvert\,\mathrm{d}\tau+
  \frac{1}{t}\int_{s}^{t}\lvert f(\tau)\rvert\,\mathrm{d}\tau\\
  &\leq\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{s}\lvert f(\tau)\rvert\,\mathrm{d}\tau+
  \frac{t-s}{t}\sup_{\tau\in[s,t]}\lvert f(\tau)\rvert\\
  &\leq\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{s}\lvert f(\tau)\rvert\,\mathrm{d}\tau+
  \frac{t-s}{t}\sup_{\tau\geq s}\,\lvert f(\tau)\rvert.
\end{align}
Taking the upper limit as $t\to\infty$, we get
\begin{equation}
  \limsup_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}\lvert f(\tau)\rvert\,\mathrm{d}\tau\leq
  \sup_{\tau\geq s}\,\lvert f(t)\rvert.
\end{equation}
Do I now simply pass to the limit as $s\to\infty$ or is there any ''trap'' I have not thought over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no trap. You proved that for all $s>0$ the inequality
$$\limsup_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t |f( \tau)| \ \mathrm d \tau \le \sup_{\tau \ge s} |f( \tau)|$$
holds. In particular, taking the infimum of RHS you get
$$\limsup_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t |f( \tau)| \ \mathrm d \tau \le \inf_{s>0} \left( \sup_{\tau \ge s} |f( \tau)| \right)$$
Which is exactly the inequality you needed:
$$\limsup_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t |f( \tau)| \ \mathrm d \tau \le \limsup_{s \to \infty} |f( s)| $$