# $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ of real sequences and their Cesaro averages

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(x_n)$ a real bounded sequence and define
$$
\sigma_n:=\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{n}
$$ 
for all $n$. Show that
$$
\liminf x_n \le \liminf \sigma_n \le \limsup \sigma_n \le \limsup x_n.
$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $\sigma_n=\frac{s_1+s_2+\cdots+s_n}{n}$ then $\operatorname{{lim sup}}\sigma_n \leq \operatorname{lim sup} s_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193157/if-sigma-n-fracs-1s-2-cdotss-nn-then-operatornamelim-sup-sigma)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prove only the last inequality (the first one is symmetric, the middle one is trivial). Set $\ell:=\limsup x_n$ and $s:=\sup x_n$. Hence, for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $n_\varepsilon$ such that
$$
x_n \le \ell+\varepsilon
$$
for all $n \ge n_\varepsilon$. Now, for all $n\ge n_\varepsilon$ large, it holds
\begin{align}
\sigma_n&=\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_{n_\varepsilon}+x_{n_\varepsilon+1}+\cdots+x_n}{n}\\
&\le \frac{s\cdot n_\varepsilon+x_{n_\varepsilon+1}+\cdots+x_n}{n}\le \ell+2\varepsilon.
\end{align}
Therefore, since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, $\limsup \sigma_n \le \ell$.

Ps. In particular, if $(x_n)$ converges, then also $(\sigma_n)$ converges.