# What is this function related with continued fractions?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, continued-fractions, golden-ratio

Playing with continued fractions, I came with the idea of iterating the limit of the simplest one:

$$1 + \cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cdots}}}}}\ = \Phi$$

And then I thoght about iterating the result:
$$\Phi + \cfrac{1}{\Phi+\cfrac{1}{\Phi+\cfrac{1}{\Phi+\cfrac{1}{\Phi+\cfrac{1}{\Phi+\cdots}}}}}\ = ?$$

And after that keep iterating again and again. Essentially, what I am doing is solving this:

$$x = a + \frac{1}{x}$$

for different values of $a$. Whose solution is:

$$ x = \frac{a \pm \sqrt{a^2 + 4}}{2}$$

And I'm just staying with the positive solution. At the end, I'm just exploring this sequence defined recursively:

$$ f(1) = \Phi \\
f(n+1) = \frac{f(n) + \sqrt{f(n)^2 + 4}}{2}
$$

When you see the plot of the terms of the sequence, you get this picture:
[image: Iterated limit of continued fractions]

I would like to know **which is the function that generates that curve**. It really seems to be a continuos function (notice that the picture is a set of points so close, that may seem to be continuous, but it's not).

So... **What's the function underlying this curve and how can we find it?**

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: When $a=1$, then it converges to the golden-ratio, when $a=2$ it converges to the silver-ratio (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_ratio) And more generaly for $a=n$ it converges to the $n$'th metalic number. I would be very tempted to say that this always converges for $a>0$ to $\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2+4}}{2}$ as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_mean.

Comment: The recursion can be written like

$$ f(n+1) - f(n) = \frac{\sqrt{f(n)^2 + 4} - f(n)}{2} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{f(n)^2 + 4} + f(n)}$$
If one at this stage removes the 4 in the denominator and solves a continuous approximation
$ f' = \frac{1}{f}$ i.e. $(f^2)' = 2$, we end up with a square root shape, which roughly agrees with the graph http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+2sqrt(x)+from+0+to+5000

Comment: I certainly can't (haven't) prove this, but it looks like something of the form $a\sqrt{bx}$ for constants $a$ and $b$.

Comment: The next correction after Calvin's formula is $f'=\frac1f-\frac1{f^3}$ which gives $2n=f^2+\log*(f^2-1)$

Comment: ... or $f(n)=\sqrt{2n-\ln(2n)}$

Answer (score 2):

This question is similar to [MSE question 1072256](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1072256) "$a_{n+1} = \log(1+a_n), a_1>0.$ ..." and to [MSE question 3215](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/3215) "Convergence of $\sqrt{n}x_n$ where $x_{n+1}=\sin(x_n)$". Because of the similarities, it is natural to assume that there is a power series
 $\, f(n) \approx f^*(n) := \sqrt{2n} \,
(1 + c_1 x - c_2 x^2 + c_3 x^3 - c_4 x^4 + O(x^5)) \,$ where $\, x := 1/n \,$ and
 $\, c_k \,$ is a polynomial of degree $k$ in $\, y := \log(x). \,$ Using the defining recursion for $\, f(n) \,$ we can solve for the coefficients $\, c_k \,$ to get
 $$ c_1 = c + y/8, \quad c_2 = (1+4c)^2/32 + (1+4c)y/32 + y^2/128,$$ $$ c_3 \!=\! \frac{11 \!+\! 120 c \!+\! 384 c^2 \!+\! 384 c^3}{768} \!+\! \frac{5 \!+\! 32 c \!+\! 48 c^2}{256} y \!+\!
\frac{1 \!+\! 3 c}{128} y^2 \!+\! \frac{y^3}{1024},$$
where $\, c\,$ is a constant depending on $\, f(0). \,$ If we use the initial values
 $\, f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1, \, f(2) = \phi, \dots, \,$
then $\, c \approx -0.291131527. \,$
Note that since $\, \sqrt{1/2}-1 \approx -0.292 \,$ the formula is already close for $\, n=1.$

To judge the accuracy, we get
$\, f(1) = 1, \,$ $ f^*(1) \approx 1.00269, \,$
$f(2) \approx 1.61803, \,$ $ f^*(2) \approx 1.61826, \,$
$f(3) \approx 2.09529, \,$ and $ f^*(3) \approx 2.09535. \,$

Answer (score 2):

*Using what has been given in comments*.

If we use $$2n=f^2+\log(f^2-1)\implies 2n-1=(f^2-1)+\log(f^2 -1)$$ let $t=(f^2-1)$ to make
$$2n-1=t+\log(t)\implies t\, e^t=e^{2n-1}\implies t=W\left(e^{2 n-1}\right)$$ where appears [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) making the final solution to be
$$f=\sqrt{1+W\left(e^{2 n-1}\right)}\tag1$$

If we use
$$n=\frac{1}{4} f \left(f+\sqrt{f^2+4}\right)+\sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{f}{2}\right)$$ and expand the rhs as a series for infinitely large values of $f$, we should get
$$n=\frac{f^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\log \left({f}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{f^2}\right)=\frac{f^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\log \left({f^2}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{f^2}\right)$$ and, ignoring the higher order terms, the same process would lead to 
$$f=\sqrt{W\left(e^{2 n-1}\right)}\tag2$$

Now, for large values of $n$, you could use the asymptotic series given in the linked Wikipedia page
$$W(x)=L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\frac{L_2(L_2-2)}{2L_1^2}+\frac{L_2(6-9L_2+2L_2^2)}{6L_1^3}+\cdots$$ where $L_1=\log(x)$ and $L_2=\log(L_1)$ and get, as a very first approximation
$$f\approx \sqrt{(2n-1)-\log(2n-1)}$$

To allow you to compare with your numbers, I generated a table of numerical values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & (1) \\
 500  & 31.5135 \\
 1000 & 44.6363 \\
 1500 & 54.6991 \\
 2000 & 63.1800 \\
 2500 & 70.6504 \\
 3000 & 77.4035 \\
 3500 & 83.6131 \\
 4000 & 89.3925 \\
 4500 & 94.8203 \\
 5000 & 99.9539
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: A little problem with your equation (1). It does not satisfy the defining recursion $f(n+1) =(f(n) + \sqrt{f(n)^2 + 4})/2$ and thus it is not clear to me how this relates to $f(n)$ in the question..

Comment: @Somos. As I wrote at the start of my answer, I just took what had already be written in comments. No more ! For sure, neither $(1)$ or $(2)$ satisfy the defining recursion but they seem to be quite close to.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can set up a differential equation and solve it.

\begin{eqnarray}
2f'(n) &= -f(n)+\sqrt{f(n)^2+4}\\
\text{d}n&=\frac{2\, \text{d}\! f}{-f+\sqrt{f^2+4}} \\
n &= \frac{1}{4} (f (f + \sqrt{4 + f^2} + 4 \sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{f}{2}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
Solving for $f$ should result in the function you wanted.
[Wolfram plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve(1%2F4%20(y%20(y%20%2B%20sqrt(4%20%2B%20y%5E2))%20%2B%204%20sinh%5E(-1)(y%2F2))%3D%3Dx,y))

Comment: Wouldn't this just be an approximation, because $f'(n) \sim f(n+1) - f(n)$ but it is not equal unless $f$ is linear.

Comment: I think you can define a discrete derivative this way, no need for $f$ to have the property of linearity.

Comment: right but then you would have to do a discrete integral (i.e. a summation) instead of a continuous integral.

Comment: I thought this would suffice as an approximation, but now I think you are correct. If I do not think of a good reason, I will delete the answer after some time

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to use the theory of continuous iterations, which is often best tackled using power series around fixed points. Let $g(z) = \frac{z + \sqrt{z^2 + 4}}2$. Then notice
$$
g^{-1}(w) = \frac{w^2 - 1}w
$$
This has no fixed points except at infinity, but we can actually make use of that if we conjugate by $w\to \frac1w$, since $h(w) = \frac1{g^{-1}(1/w)}$ will have a fixed point at $w=0$. We can see the series for $h(w)$ is given by $$
h(w) = \frac{w}{1-w^2} = w + w^3 + w^5 + ...
$$
Formally composing this series with itself is fairly straightforward, for example:
\begin{eqnarray}
h(h(w)) &=& (w + w^3 + w^5 +...) + (w + w^3 + w^5 +...)^3 + (w + w^3 + w^5 +...)^5 + ...
\\ &=& w + 2w^3 + 2w^5 + ...
\end{eqnarray}
In general, we will have
$$
h^n(x) = w + p_3(n)w^3 + p_5(n)w^5 + ...
$$
where $p_i(n)$ satisfy a recurrence given by
\begin{equation}
w + p_3(n+1) w^3 + p_5(n+1)w^5 + ... = h^{n+1}(x) = h(h^n(x)) \\ = (w + p_3(n)w^3 + p_5(n)w^5 + ...) + (w + p_3(n)w^3 + p_5(n)w^5 + ...)^3 + (w + p_3(n)w^3 + p_5(n)w^5 + ...)^5 + ... \\ = w + (p_3(n) + 1) w^3 + (p_5(n) + 3p_3(n) + 1) w^5 + ...
\end{equation}
We get recursions like $p_3(n+1) = p_3(n) + 1$. Clearly, this is solved by $p_3(n) = n$. The $w^5$ coefficient is $p_5(n+1) = p_5(n) + 3n + 1$, which is solved by $p_5(n) = n + \frac32 n(n+1)$. In general, you can actually find a unique polynomial for each $p_i(n)$ by using [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) since each one is defined by a recursion $p_i(n+1) = p_i(n) + q_i(n)$ for some appropriate polynomial $q_i(n)$. Notice this recursion will still be satisfied for noninteger $n$, so we have a function $H(t,w) = w + p_3(t)w^3 + p_5(t)w^5 +...$ satisfying:
$$
 H(t+1,w) = h(H(t,w))
$$
OK so what does this have to do with the original question? Well, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
H(t+1,w) &=& \frac1{g^{-1}(1/H(t,w))} \\
\frac1{H(t+1,w)} &=& g^{-1}\left(\frac1{H(t,w)}\right) \\
g\left(\frac1{H(t+1,w)}\right) &=& \frac1{H(t,w)}
\end{eqnarray}
substituting $-n = t+1$, and recalling the definition of $g$, we find:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac1{H(-(n+1),w)} &=& g\left(\frac1{H(-n,w)}\right) \\
\frac1{H(-(n+1),w)} &=& \frac{\frac1{H(-n,w)} + \sqrt{\frac1{H(-n,w)^2} + 4}}2
\end{eqnarray}
Then, as you can see, we will have $f(n) = \frac1{H(-n,w)}$, where $w$ is the starting value. I do not expect this function to have a nice closed form.

This formula for $f$ is only helpful on a small scale, but it does demonstrate we can draw a smooth (hence continuous) function through those points. If you want to know about the asymptotic behavior of $f(n)$ as $n\to\infty$, somos has already covered that in his answer.

Comment: What you describe won't really solve the problem. That is, you won't get the correct behavior $\, f(n) \sim \sqrt{2n}.$ In particular this approach won't give the logarithms in the series expansion.

Comment: Yea I guess it doesn't give any information about the asymptotics of $f$.

Comment: The main thing this solution gives is a smooth interpolation that still satisfies the recursion

Comment: Yes, it does, but only locally. I have used similar methods myself for this kind of problem, but I know it has severe limitations. It is similar to polynomial interpolation. It doesn't work well for extrapolation.

Comment: Definitely a valid point! Of course, given $f$ locally you can use the recursion to extend it, but you need an asymptotic expansion to know what that will look like. I don't really have anything to contribute with regards to asymptotics, I think you covered that in your answer perfectly well.