# Limit of $nx_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Okay, so I have this problem:

Given the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ defined by $x_{n+1}=\dfrac{3x_n^2}{(1+x_n)^3-1}$, with $x_1>0$, find $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}nx_n$.

I've proved that the first limit equals $0$, by proving the sequence is bounded and monotonic, but I have no idea what to do about the second one. Could you give me a **hint**?

Comment: Bounded and monotonic gives you that the sequence converges, and to something that is no MORE/LESS than the bound,  not that the sequence converges to 0

Comment: @Alan Who is good understanding doesn't need many words. The sequence is always positive and the limit satisfies $x(x+3)=0$.

Comment: @pp.. I would argue that it's important to not put down incorrect words,  as it would lead to trying to use similar reasoning in future problems where you don't have the additional information that makes it true

Comment: @Alan don't worry, I know how the first one is done. I've also shown that if it converges, it must converge to $0$, so that's not a problem. The problem is I have no idea how to do the second one.

Comment: @ryagami An idea, as in undertermined limit on the reals, is to use L'Hospital. Well, for sequences it is called Stolz's theorem (check the spelling, I never know how to spell his name). So, instead of computing the limit of $nx_n=\frac{n}{1/x_n}$, we compute the limit of $\frac{(n+1)-n}{\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{x_n}}$. So, essentially one needs to deal with $\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{x_n}$.

Comment: Notice now, that from the given recurrence you can write the recurrence for $1/x_n$ and with it study its increments.

Comment: @Pp.. Okay, I'm so stupid. Stolz does it fine. Thanks!

Comment: @Alan "proved A by B" doesn't mean that B is the whole proof. So the statement is not incorrect. As I said "A bon entendeur ..."

Comment: @Pp.. I think that mathematical statements/proofs must be crystal clearly written and explained, otherwise things can go wrong pretty easily. Alan was right in remarking that monotone + bounded sequence does **not** give, at all, that the limit  is zero. That the limit fulfills $\;x(x+3)=0\;$ is something *you* had to work out, not something that stems from the OP's question, in particular when he addresses Alan's comment he says that "I proved that if it converges then it converges to zero", and this begs the question: did you prove the seq. is mon. and bounded or not?

Comment: @Timbuc That is what you think. What I think is that way too often those who don't know how to solve a problem like to pick on the irrelevant and obvious. I enjoy calling upon that type of people.

Comment: I can't see how the comment by Alan is irrelevant: it is not only relevant but also true. What you enjoy or not *is irrelevant* for the mathematical side of this problem.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/3220/1102

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So that the question doesn't appear as unanswered.

Following the hint I wrote in the comment we use Stolz's theorem with $\frac{n}{1/x_n}$.

> The given recurrence is equivalent to $$x_{n+1}=\frac{3x_n}{x_n^2+3x_n+3}.$$ If we write $y_n:=1/x_n$ then we get $$y_{n+1}=y_n+1+\frac{1}{3y_n}$$ from where $$y_{n+1}-y_n=1+\frac{1}{3y_n}\to1$$ Therefore $\frac{(n+1)-n}{y_{n+1}-y_n}\to1$. By Stolz's theorem we get that $nx_n=\frac{n}{1/x_n}=\frac{n}{y_n}\to 1$.

Comment: Just one thing - it's $3x_n^2$ in the numerator. :)

Comment: @ryagami which got cancelled with a factor $x_n$ in the denominator. Check it carefully anyway, I constantly make mistakes of all sorts.

Comment: Then why am I getting 1 as the answer?

Comment: @ryagami Because it is indeed $1$ and I don't know how to divide $3/3$.

Comment: Hm, that would be it. :)