# Is this a convergent series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Put $a_{0}= \pi/2$  and  $a_{n}=\sin(a_{n-1})$.

> Is  $\sum a_{n}$ a convergent  series?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: @Siminore  Thank  you for  your  edit. I have  no idea  for  this  series. But this  question can introduce the  following  concept in non hyperbolic  fixed points of  maps (Then can  be  adapted  for flows): WLOG we  may  assume that  the  fixed point  of  a  function $f$  is $0$. We say $0$ is  a conditionally  fixed point if for every $p$ in a small  neighborhood of $0$ $\sum f^{n} (p)$ converges. Of course this  is the case for hyperbolic attractors.one can even think about the  generalization for dynamics  an  arbitrary [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_manifold] (affine  manifolds)

Comment: Duplicate of https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1059961_does_sum_a_n_converge_if_a_n_sin_sin__sinx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does $\sum a_n$ converge if $a_n = \sin( \sin (...( \sin(x))...)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1176894/does-sum-a-n-converge-if-a-n-sin-sin-sinx)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_manifold

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  thank you  for  the  link.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  thanks  for the  link.