# Conditionally hyperbolic attractor

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-point-iteration

Motivated by [this  post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1176894/does-sum-a-n-converge-if-a-n-sin-sin-sinx) and  the  comment- conversation   of [this  post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2227310/is-this-a-convergent-series) we  consider the  following definition:

Assume that $f$ is  a map on  a  neighborhood of $0$  with $f(0)=0$.
We  say that $0$ is a conditionally hyperbolic  attractor if for  every $p$ sufficiently close to $0$, the series $\sum f^{n}(p)$ is a  convergent  series.  This concept  is  invariant under a  linear change of  coordinate. So it  can be  defined on any  arbitrary [Affine manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_manifold).

What is  an example  of a local  homeomorphism with a conditionally hyperbolic attractor at $0$ but  $0$  is  not  a  hyperbolic fixed point.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that $\sum f^n(p)$ converges while the *rate* at which $f^n(p) \to 0$ is only polynomial in $n$ and not geometric. I cooked up the example

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{x}{x-1} & x < 0 \\ - \frac{x}{x+1} & x > 0 \\
0 & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$

Clearly $f$ is continuous and defined in a neighborhood of $0$, and $f(0) = 0$ while $f'(0) = -1$ (from both sides) so that $f$ is not hyperbolic. It is asymptotically stable however, as one can check by looking at forward iterates of intervals of the form $[0,1/n]$ and $[-1/n,0]$ for $n \geq 2$. Since $f(1/n) = -(1/n)/(1+1/n)= - 1/(n+1)$ we have $$f([0,1/n]) = f([-1/(n+1), 0])$$
and since $f(-1/n) = (-1/n)/(-1-1/n)=1/(n+1)$ we have $$f([-1/n,0]) = [0,1/(n+1)]$$

These arguments imply $\sum f^n(p)$ converges conditionally for $p$ sufficiently close to $0$ as an alternating series.

One could also construct an example sending $1/n^2 \to 1/(n+1)^2$, in which case $\sum f^n(p)$ converges absolutely while $0$ is a nonhyperbolic fixed point.