# Does the series $\sum \sin^{(n)}(1)$ converge, where $\sin^{(n)}$ denotes the $n$-fold composition of $\sin$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to solve the following task

> Sequence $\{a_n\}$ is given by the rule: $a_1 = 1,\: a_{n+1} = \sin (a_n)$. Does the series $\sum a_n$ converge?

Can you give me any hints how to solve it, cause i got totally stuck at the very beginning, please?

Comment: @Misakov if series converges than $a_n \to 0$, but $a_n$can converge either monotonically either not, doesnt it?

Comment: It is indeed monotonically decreasing because of $\sin(x)<x$ (for $x>0$). But it is still not trivial to see whether it converges or not (imo). My first guess would be divergence.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1176894/does-sum-a-n-converge-if-a-n-sin-sin-sinx).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The series diverges. To see this, first note that
$$
a_1 = 1\ge 1
$$
and that, if $a_n \ge 1/n$, then
$$
a_{n+1} = \sin(a_n) \ge \sin(1/n) > 1/(n+1)
$$
By induction, we have $a_n \ge 1/n$ for all $n$. Since $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ diverges, so does $\sum a_n$.

Note that $(n+1)\sin(1/n) > 1$ can be shown by Taylor expansion.

Answer (score 2):

Just an intuition:

Since $sin(x)$ almost equals $x$ for values of $x$ near $0$, so it's like adding the same term infinitely with hardly any change in it...so it would diverge for sure!

Answer (score 0):

If you look up
"iterated sine"
you will find that
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n}\sin^{(n)}(x)
=\sqrt{3}
$
independent of $x$.

See, for example,
http://jonathan.bergknoff.com/journal/iterated-sine

Therefore
$\sin^{(n)}(x)
\approx \sqrt{\dfrac{3}{n}}
$.
Since
$\sum \dfrac1{\sqrt{n}}$
diverges,
$\sum \sin^{(n)}(x)
$
diverges.

Even more is true.
Since
$(\sin^{(n)}(x))^2
\approx \dfrac{3}{n}
$,
$\sum (\sin^{(n)}(x))^2
$
diverges.