# Does the following $\sin$-series converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $a_0=1$ and $a_{n} = \sin(a_{n-1})$. Does the following series
$$
\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n
$$
converges?

I have no ideas...

Comment: Various postings, such as [*this*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3215/convergence-of-sqrtnx-n-where-x-n1-sinx-n), show that $a_n$ is asymptotically $\sqrt{3/n}$. Given this, what can you say about the sum?

Comment: @SangchulLee,  I can say that the sum is diverges)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a_n \geq\frac{1}{n}  (n \geq2)$, because

if $a_{n-1} \geq \frac{1}{n-1},$ then $ a_n = \sin(a_{n-1}) \geq \sin(\frac{1}{n-1}) \geq \frac{1}{n}$

[reason of $\sin(\frac{1}{n-1} ) \geq \frac{1}{n} (n\geq2)$ (graph)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMJu5.png)

so $\sum a_n \geq \sum \frac{1}{n}=\infty$