# Determine the convergence of the recursion $x_n=\sin(x_{n-1})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

I want to determine the convergence of $$\begin{cases}x_0=1 &  \\
x_n=\sin(x_{n-1}) 
\end{cases}$$
I can see that $x_n=\sin(x_{n-1}) \geq -1$. Which means the sequence is bounded. However, it isn't strictly decreasing in $[-1,1]$, so I can't prove that it is convergent. Is there a way to get a better bound and show that it goes to $0$?

Comment: The answer to your question is here [Convergence of $\sqrt{n}x_{n}$ where $x_{n+1} = \sin(x_{n})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3215/convergence-of-sqrtnx-n-where-x-n1-sinx-n).

Comment: It *is* stricktly decreasing. The inequality $\sin(x) \leq x$ is useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you can easily prove that $]0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ is stable by $\sin$ therefore your sequence $(x_n)_n$ is valued in $]0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ since $1 \in ]0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ .

You can use the inequality :

$$\sin{x} <x, \quad \forall x >0$$

to prove that $x_{n+1} \leq x_n$ and your sequence is strictly decreasing and bounded by $0$ so it converges.

Then, by the continuity of $x \mapsto \sin(x)$, you know the sequence converges toward the solution of $\sin{l}=l$, i.e $l=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\sin(x)\leq x$ so $x_n=\sin(x_{n-1})\leq x_{n-1}$.