# Given a sequence with $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=a_n-\frac13a_n^2$. Is there an easier way to get an upper bound of $1/a_{100}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations, alternative-proof

Suppose that a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ satisfies $a_1=1$ and $$a_{n+1}=a_n-\frac13a_n^2,\qquad n=1,2,3,\cdots.$$
Which of the following is true?

(A) $2<100a_{100}<\frac52$

(B) $\frac52<100a_{100}<3$

(C) $3<100a_{100}<\frac72$

(D) $\frac72<100a_{100}<4$

This problem comes from my sister's final exam (she is in high school). I have a solution, but my solution is unsatisfactory since it requires some rather complicated computation, which seems impossible to  finish during an exam.

**My solution.** Note that the recurrence relation can be rewritten as
$$\frac1{a_{n+1}}=\frac1{a_n}+\frac1{3-a_n},\qquad n=1,2,3,\cdots.$$
Therefore,
$$\frac1{a_{100}}=1+\sum_{n=1}^{99}\frac1{3-a_n}.$$
It follows from the original recurrence relation that $a_n$ is decresing and thus $a_n\leq 1$. Using $\frac1{3-a_n}\geq \frac13$, we have $$\frac1{a_{100}}\geq 1+\frac{99}3=\frac{102}3,$$which implies that $100a_{100}\leq \frac{300}{102}<3$. Hence (C) and (D) are excluded. My gut told me that (B) should be the right answer, since $a_n$ will decreasing to $0$ (an exercise for those who are just learning the concept of limits,) in which case $\frac1{3-a_n}$ is almost $\frac13$. Let's check the correctness of (B). After some calculations we have
$$a_1=1,\qquad a_2=\frac23,\qquad a_3=\frac{14}{27},\qquad a_4=\frac{67\times 14}{27^2\times 3}=\frac{938}{2187}.$$
Since $a_n\leq a_4$ for $n\geq 4$, we have
$$\frac1{a_{100}}\leq 1+\frac12+\frac37+\frac1{3-\frac{14}{27}}+\frac1{3-\frac{938}{2187}}\times 96\approx 39.66<40,$$
where I turned to a caculator. Therefore, $100a_{100}>\frac52$. Note: I tried to use $a_3$ rather than $a_4$, which was easier to compute, but it turned out that using only $a_3$ was not enough to get the desired bound.

**My question.** Is there any other methods to get the upper bound of $1/a_{100}$? I want a method involving not so many caclulations. At least they can be completed in an exam in which calculators are not allowed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is pretty similar to a famous exercise about the rate of convergence of the sequence defined by $a_{n+1}=\sin(a_n)$. In your case it is pretty simple to notice that $\{a_n\}$ is positive and decreasing, hence convergent to zero, and by setting $b_n=1/a_n$ (as you cleverly did) we have

$$ b_{n+1} = b_n + \frac{b_n}{3b_n-1}= b_n+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{9b_n-3}\tag{1}$$
where
$$ b_{n+1} \geq b_n + \frac{1}{3}$$
implies
$$ b_n \geq \frac{n+2}{3} \tag{2}$$
and $a_{100}\leq \frac{3}{102}$, which only leaves options $(A)$ and $(B)$. At this point one might guess that $(2)$ is pretty tight, hence $100 a_{100}$ is less than $3$ but pretty close to $3$ (option $\mathbf{(B)}$). Proving this requires a lower bound for $a_n$, i.e. an upper bound for $b_n$, which we can obtain by plugging $(2)$ back into $(1)$ (*bootstrapping*):
$$ b_{n+1} \leq b_n + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{n+1} \tag{3}$$
leads to
$$ b_n \leq \frac{n+H_n+1}{3} \tag{4}$$
hence $100 a_{100}\geq \frac{300}{101+H_{100}}\geq 2.8 $ and $\mathbf{(B)}$ actually is the correct answer.

An accurate approximation of $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$ comes from $H_n\approx \log(n)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.

A more elementary approximation of $H_{100}$ (a worse one, but still effective for our purposes) can be derived without calculators, using just telescopic series and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:

$$\begin{eqnarray*} H_{100} = \frac{25}{12}+\sum_{k=5}^{100}\frac{1}{k} \leq \frac{25}{12}+\sum_{k=5}^{100}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k(k-1)}}\leq \frac{25}{12}+\sqrt{\sum_{k=5}^{100}1 \sum_{k=5}^{100}\frac{1}{k(k-1)}}\end{eqnarray*}$$

leads to

$$ H_{100} \leq \frac{25}{12}+\sqrt{96\sum_{k=5}^{100}\left(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}\right)}=\frac{25}{12}+\sqrt{96\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{100}\right)}\leq \frac{25}{12}+\sqrt{24} \leq 7 $$

then to $100\,a_{100} \geq 3-\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: How do you know that $\frac{300}{101+H_{100}} \ge 2.8$?

Comment: @jjagmath: it is enough to have a decent approximation of $\log(10)$, I added a last line about it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I would like to estimate $H_{100}$  in the way that $H_{100}\leq 1+\frac12\times6+\frac18\times93=\frac{125}8<19$ if I'm taking an exam. That's enough to make sure the correctness of (B). Yes, $2.8$ is a more accurate approximation! I'll accept this answer after $20$ hours if there is no other one.

Comment: @Feng: I also added a calculators-free proof of $H_{100}\leq 7$, leading to the slightly worse lower bound $100 a_{100} \geq 3-\frac{1}{4}.$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio That's soooooo nice! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Say we have the recurrence

$$a_{n+1} = a_n -  \frac{a_n^2}{A},$$
with $a_1<A$. Write $a_n = \frac{A}{ b_n}$ and we get

$$\frac{A}{ b_{n+1}} = \frac{A}{ b_n} - \frac{A^2}{A b_n^2}$$

and so $\frac{1}{b_{n+1}} = \frac{1}{b_n} - \frac{1}{b_n^2}$
or
$$b_{n+1}= 1 + \frac{1}{b_n-1}$$

Therefore

$$b_{n+1} = b_1 + n + \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{b_k-1}\ \ (*)$$

From here we get the first estimates

$$b_1 + (n-1) < b_n < b_1 +(n-1) + (n-1) \frac{1}{b_1 -1}$$

We plug this back ( $n\mapsto k$) into the equality $(*)$ and get better estimates

$\bf{Added:}$

Let's see how to proceed with other recurrences. Say we have

$$a_{n+1} = a_n( 1- \frac{a_n^2}{6})$$

(reminiscent of $a_{n+1} = \sin a_n$). We get for the sequence $b_n \colon =\frac{3}{a_n^2}$

$$b_{n+1} = b_n + 1 + \frac{3 b_n-1}{(2 b_n-1)^2}= b_n + 1 + \frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2 b_n-1} + \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{(2b_n-1)^2}$$

We get $b_n\to \infty$, $b_{n+1}- b_n \to 1$, $\frac{b_n}{n}\to 1$, so   asymptotics of $a_n$. But also some effective estimates ( this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3215/convergence-of-sqrtnx-n-where-x-n1-sinx-n/4328745#4328745) is related, and suggests a general approach).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I think the formula $(*)$ should be $b_{n+1}=b_n+1+\frac1{b_n-1}$. Would you please check it again?

Comment: @Feng: Yes indeed, thanks!  Let me correct it real quick

Comment: @Feng: I clicked on it and it corrected itself.... then I realized you just corrected it... yes, very good, thanks!

Comment: This is a very nice answer! Thank you for letting me see a more general picture! -:)

Comment: @Feng: Wouldn't have happened without your question. And Jack D'Aurizio, he really likes the Harmonic numbers. You are very welcome!